# css3 formatting mutiple elements but not all of them

Tags: html, css

I have buttons I want to format with css I have found 2 options to format them: `#id {}` or `button {}` If I use `#ID {}` I can format a single button, if I use `button {}` I format all buttons on the page. I have different size buttons and I want to format a "group" of them. It's very annoying to format them with `#id`, is it possible to give them a group or use the same name for them and acces it with css?

Comment: You want to read up on CSS Specificity. Take a look here http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ Also take a look at CSS SpeciFISHity http://www.standardista.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/specifishity1.pdf ( For a giggle )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ID's` use `classes`

**HTML**

```
/* Group 1*/

<button class="group1"></button>
<button class="group1"></button>
<button class="group1"></button>
<button class="group1"></button>

/* Group 2*/
<button class="group2"></button>
<button class="group2"></button>
<button class="group2"></button>
<button class="group2"></button>
```

**CSS**

```
.group1
{
Formatting Comes here..!!
}


.group2
{
Formatting Comes here..!!
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks Ill use classes that was excatly waht I was searching for.

Comment: @mystd You are Welcome.. :-) And my suggestion is to Use http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp for the basics of CSS. This will help you a lot..Finally Happy Coding..:-)

Comment: @Sreeram: +1 for the right answer. But be carefuly of suggesting w3schools; they've got a bad reputation around here. (see http://w3fools.com/ for more info on why)

Comment: @Spudley : Oh Fine because of you i came to know that...Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target the buttons in general than you can safely use

```
button { /* This will target all buttons */
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Or wrap them inside a container element, give it a class like

```
<div class="wrap_all_btn">
   <!-- All button goes here -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrap_all_btn button { 
   /* This will target buttons which are only inside a div 
      element having class .wrap_all_btn */
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

To target buttons inside the wrapper uniquely, you can use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` but I would prefer `nth-of-type` here as it is element specific, so if you want to target say 2nd button in the wrapper we made so you can write it like

```
div.wrap_all_btn button {
   /* This is where general styles go */
}


div.wrap_all_btn button:nth-of-type(2) {
   /* Create Unique Styles For 2nd Button Without Making Any Class */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

styleClass defined inside html object.

```
<input type ="button" class = "myClass" ...(other values like value or id ...)/>
```

in css:

```
.myClass {
   //styling

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="myClass">
```

CSS:

```
.myClass { width: 150px; }
```

Source:
http://www.quackit.com/css/tutorial/css_class.cfm

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class and group your buttons on the basis of the different class attributes that you want to apply.

like

```
.button1{color:blue;}
.button2{color:red;}
.button3{color:green;}
```

So by doing this, you can apply multiple instances of the same classes as many times you want them to apply to your different buttons.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add few classes to element:

```
.button{font-size: 15px; color: #ff0000;...}
.button.small{font-size: 12px;}
.button.large{font-size: 18px;}

<input type="button" class="button" />
<input type="button" class="button small" />
<input type="button" class="button large" />
```